# writing p-values to file in R

Tags: file, r

Can someone help me with this piece of code. In a loop I'm saving p-values in f and then I want to write the p-values to a file but I don't know which function to use to write to file. I'm getting error with write function.

```
{
f = fisher.test(x, y = NULL, hybrid = FALSE, alternative = "greater",
                conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95, simulate.p.value = FALSE)

write(f, file="fisher_pvalues.txt", sep=" ", append=TRUE)
}

Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Comment: Just wanted to thank @Helen for providing full code and the full error message.  Yes it's a n00b question, but w/ this info it's easy to provide the proper answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value from fisher.test is (if you read the docs):

> Value:
>
> ```
>  A list with class ‘"htest"’ containing the following components:
> ```
>
> p.value: the p-value of the test.
>
> conf.int: a confidence interval for the odds ratio.  Only present in
>             the 2 by 2 case and if argument ‘conf.int = TRUE’.

etc etc. R doesn't know how to write things like that to a file. More precisely, it doesn't know how YOU want it written to a file.

If you just want to write the p value, then get the p value and write that:

```
 write(f$p.value,file="foo.values",append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Or you can use `save` to write the entire object to a file.

Comment: @joran -- It looks like Helen wants the results in a *.txt file, so it's worth noting that `save` writes an R-specific binary representation of the object to the file.

Answer (score 4):

`f` is an object of class `'htest'`, so writing it to a file will write much more than just the p-value.

If you *do* want to simply save a written representation of the results to a file, just as they appear on the screen, you can use `capture.output()` to do so:

```
Convictions <-
   matrix(c(2, 10, 15, 3),
          nrow = 2,
          dimnames =
          list(c("Dizygotic", "Monozygotic"),
               c("Convicted", "Not convicted")))
 f <- fisher.test(Convictions, alternative = "less")

 capture.output(f, file="fisher_pvalues.txt", append=TRUE)
```

More likely, you want to just store the p-value. In that case you need to extract it from `f` before writing it to the file, using code something like this:

```
 write(paste("p-value from Experiment 1:", f$p.value, "\n"), 
       file = "fisher_pvalues.txt", append=TRUE)
```